# Should I user Paypal on the server side or client side for a Phonegap App?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cordova, paypal, phonegap-plugins

I'm working on a new shop app where people can buy tickets. I would like to use Paypal as a payement system directly from the app. I don't want my users to leave the app.

I saw online there are librairies for Paypal on both client end and server end.
Cordova/Phonegap plugin : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin
CodeIgniter / PHP plugin : https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library

First question : Do I need to integrate both platforms ?
If no, what is the best option, should I do the payment on the server or directly from the customer's phone ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cordova-Plugin is built on top of PayPal Mobile SDK libraries, which provides a native in-app payment for your integration.

Literally you would be able to implement your complete payment flow with mobile platform SDK only (skip the payment-verify step on the server side), but that will necessarily depend on what your use cases are.

Here're the recommended solutions that will need some work on both platforms

The payment can be either (1) an immediate payment which your servers should subsequently verify, or (2) an authorization for a payment which your servers must subsequently capture, or (3) a payment for an order which your servers must subsequently authorize and capture

You may want to check [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/) for some instructions on how the server side works for a mobile payment

*For the record, the AngellEYE PHP library is for PayPal classic APIs and is irrelevant to this topic. Mobile payments are using REST apis and you may refer to the [REST API PHP SDK](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/) for server-end implementations*